# Django: How to get a person whose birthday is today from a database?

Tags: python, django, database

Good afternoon, I recently started programming with Django and there was a slight difficulty with displaying the date of birth of a person whose birthday is today from the database, can anyone come across this?
model.py

```
class HapB(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Имя', max_length=50)
    last_n = models.CharField('Фамилия', max_length=50)
    Otdel = models.CharField('Отдел', max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField('Дата рождения', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best and the simplest approach is this:

```
from django.utils import timezone

HapB.objects.filter(date_of_birth__day=timezone.now().date().day, date_of_birth__day=timezone.now().date().month)
```

Or if your app is not timezone aware:

```
from datetime import datetime

HapB.objects.filter(date_of_birth__day=datetime.now().date().day, date_of_birth__month=datetime.now().date().month)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try out

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time

today = datetime.now().date()
tomorrow = today + timedelta(1)
today_start = datetime.combine(today, time())
today_end = datetime.combine(tomorrow, time())

HapB.objects.filter(date_of_birth__lte=today_end,date_of_birth__gte=today_start)
```

Comment: I think this is very overthought and it also might not work with timezone aware applications :)

Comment: Hey correct, liked your solution better @NixonSparrow

Comment: Your answer helped me and indeed it displays the date but only if it was born this year